# Installing Skype in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, skype

I'm new to Linux. I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed. I'm trying to install Skype. I downloaded the package:

```
skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386
```

When I open the package, I'm taken to a window that gives information about Skype and has an "install" button.

When I click "install", it says "installing" for a fraction of a second, before reverting back to "install" - but nothing has happened. There is no error message or anything giving me any further information.

I am running a 64 bit system.

How can I install Skype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install skype you need to **Enable The Canonical Partners Repository**

open the terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

To perform an installation of i386 package on 64-bit system we need to enable multi-architecture to support both platforms.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Update and install skype:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

Also you can install it manually.

Download the `.deb` package from the official website (e,g):

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: @Tom Kelly Sorry , the following edit `skype-ubuntu-xenial_4.3.0.37-1_i386.deb` doesn't work , because the package isn't avaible.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has a built in installer for many "packages" or software including Skype. Run this code in the terminal to install with automatic detection of your Ubuntu version:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install skype
```

This will ask for your account password similar to how Mac or PC requires permission from an admin account to install software.

You can get the details of the package with:

```
apt-cache show skype
```

This should show you the details for any package you want more details on (such as additional LaTeX packages). You could also use the "Ubuntu Software Centre" app to search and install packages. If you have downloaded a .deb file you can run `dpkg -i filename.deb` or open it in the software centre.

However I recommend the `apt-get` method as it works for the majority of packages and is worth getting familiar with.

Note also that "precise" is a codename for a previous version of ubuntu. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS IS codenamed "xenial" (the increase alphabetically) so any files you download or "ppa's" you use must match your version of Ubuntu (or the version of Ubuntu it has been based on for other distributions also using this package manager).

Comment: Note also that questions specifically about Ubuntu may be better suited (or already answered) on the [Ask Ubuntu forum](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=install+skype).

Comment: I got the following: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package skype

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install skype`

Comment: This updates the packages lists. This should only be necessary after a fresh install or adding a PPA host. You can then also run `sudo apt-get upgrade` will get the latest versions of the packages installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

At times I get the easiest way to install skype.
At other time, I get stuck when the the meeting with client is just 5 minutes away.

Below is the easiest way I found:

Run the below commands in the terminal.

*sudo apt-get update*

*sudo apt-get upgrade*

Download Skype with the command below:

*wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb*

Now go to the download folder from the terminal and run the below command.

*dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb*

After this, click "search your computer" icon at the top left corner of the Ubuntu Desktop. It will show "Skype" as installed app/software. Click on the Skype icon and start the application.

Thanks Senjam